# "autosizing" seems not to work in small TextViews

Tags: android, android-gridlayout, autosize

I want to design a 27x27 GridLayout. Every cell in the grid contains only one character. To make the GridLayout as big as possible, I constrain the GridLayout to the top and bottom of the screen (in landscape orientation). To optimize legibility, I use "autosizing" in the TextViews.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/SCFrame"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
tools:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
>

<android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout
    android:id="@+id/SudokuGrid"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:tag="SudokuGrid"
    app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    >


    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
        android:id="@+id/A11"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="1"
        app:autoSizeMinTextSize="5sp"
        app:autoSizeStepGranularity="1sp"
        app:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
        app:layout_column="0"
        app:layout_columnWeight="1"
        app:layout_row="0"
        app:layout_rowWeight="1" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
        android:id="@+id/A12"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="2"
        app:autoSizeMinTextSize="5sp"
        app:autoSizeStepGranularity="1sp"
        app:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
        app:layout_column="1"
        app:layout_columnWeight="1"
        app:layout_row="0"
        app:layout_rowWeight="1" />

... repeat this for 27 columns and 27 rows in total;
you just need to complete the first line and the first column to be able to reproduce the problem
```

Using Android Studio 3.0 this layout displays correctly on the "Nexus 10", "Pixel C" and "Nexus 9" emulators, in landscape orientation. But it fails for all other emulators.
Handling of heights seems to be a problem. Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

Setting the min text size property worked for me in a similar situation:

```
    <item name="android:autoSizeTextType">uniform</item>
    <item name="android:autoSizeMinTextSize">8sp</item>
```

Comment: My question dates back on 19 NOV 2017; they might have fixed the issue since that date

Answer (score -1):

use this [AutoFitTextView](https://github.com/grantland/android-autofittextview)
it help you may be.